# How to move(animate) a button to a certain position on click and return to original position if click elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose we have a button `<button id="btn">I'm a button</button>`.It's position is right in the center.Now when i click this button it should move to let's say top left corner.When click elsewhere on screen return the button to original position(center), so that next time i click the button it should repeat the transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.animate()` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the easiest solution for you. Pure css without any javascripts.

```css
#btn {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-right: -84px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
#btn:focus {
  top:0;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">I'm a button</button>
```

You can also use jquery, binding "focus" and "blur" event on the button, and animate it to the #btn:focus style values.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it with javascript maybe like this you mean https://jsfiddle.net/90c23wbr/

```
<div class="text-center">
  <button id="button" class='btn btn-primary to-center'>button</button>
</div>
```

css :

```
.btn {
  position:absolute;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
.to-center {
  top:50%;
}
.to-top {
  top:5%;
}
```

and js:

```
var removeClass = true;

$("#button").click(function () {
   $(".btn").addClass('to-top');
   removeClass = false;
});

$("#button").click(function() {
  removeClass = false;
});

$("html").click(function () {
   if (removeClass) {
     $(".btn").removeClass('to-top');
   }
   removeClass = true;
});
```